# Plot and rearrange values in ascending order in seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want plot values in ascending order for both x and y axis

**Code**

```
color_dict = dict({'1':'orange',
                  '2':'steelblue',
                  '3':'lightgreen', 
                   '4': 'purple'
                  })    

sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'grid.linestyle': '-'})
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

ax1=sns.scatterplot(data=df2, x="x", y="y", hue="result",markers= 'x',s=950, palette= color_dict )
#ax1.set(xlabel=None, ylabel=None, xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])
#ax1.set_yticks((0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5), minor=0)
#ax1.set_xticks([0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.6], minor=False)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.setp(ax1.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='14') # for legend text
ax1.plot()
```

**Plot**

[image]

**Goal**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Your x and y are probably strings instead of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change data type to `int` or `float`

```
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(int)
df['y'] = df['y'].astype(int)
```